# Getting time range

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the date and time before I create it on ssrs.
For example I have a parameter `time` which is

```
@FROMDATE ='2016-10-01 6:00 AM'
```

and

```
@TODATE ='2016-10-04 6:00 AM'
```

I want to get 6:00 am - 6:00 am(24hrs). the Value that I want to display is that '2016-10-1 to 2016-10-3 6-6 am' even if the range date is `2016-10-04`.

I hope you understand my problem. TIA!

Comment: what format is your date stored in?

Comment: You should explain more. What do you want to do with that parameter?

Comment: another example if my date range is '2016-10-1 6:00 am to '2016-10-2 6:00 am' I want to display 24hrs data between the range date but the Date that will be displayed will be 2016-10-1. sorry I cant explain it deeply its hard for me to explain it in English :3